# Take python input data directly from a Jupyter cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, user-input, jupyter-lab

I would like to create an interactive notebook with Jupiter Lab. My idea is to use this notebook for teaching Python programming in a similar way to some platforms like hackerrank do, using tescases with different input sets. The students should write their code in a jupyter cell and this code would be tested taking the input from another cell.

To illustrate this wiht an easy example, I may ask a student to write a program that takes two numbers and prints their sum. Every number is given on a separate line.
The student could write the following program in a code cell:

```
x = (int)(input())
y = (int)(input())
print(x+y)
```

An then I would provide a test case in another cell with the following input data for that program:

```
5
6
```

I would give the result (11) in another cell and the student should execute his program and compare the result.

At first, I thought about providing the input datasets in dataframes imported from a csv file included in the notebook, but then I was wondering if something as in the former example (taking the input dataset directly from a jupyter cell) would be possible.

Comment: This isn't how the cells in Jupyter work and so I'm unsure why you are deciding on this approach? You can though use ipywidgets and make a **cell-like text input widget** & then use that to do your calculations. This can be done in a Jupyter notebook and then you can use [Voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila) to make an app interface for your users. If you insist on customizing JupyterLab, you may want to look into [ipylab](https://github.com/jtpio/ipylab) although I'm not sure how easily you'd get close to what your post proposes. Additionally, you could maybe hack on JupyterLite.

Comment: Additionally, an extension may be what is needed. [Here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/extension-to-add-a-new-command-to-execute-cells-below-selected-cells/23132?u=fomightez) someone made an extension using ipylab to do a variation of what Jupyter currently allows. JupyterLab has a rich extensible extensions ability, see [here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extensions.html) to get started looking into that. I think this also may be a reasonable option to pursue aside from uwing ipywidgets and Voila.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a cell in a Jupyter notebook, you see something like `In [2]:` to the left of the cell after it is executed. To the left of the resulting output cell you will see `Out[2]:`

In IPython, `In` is a list data structure that stores each executed code cell as a text string preserving the order. The list is initialized with an empty string as the first entry, so `In[1]` contains the first code cell executed in the session.

```py
type(In)
>>>> list
```

`Out` is a standard dictionary that uses the cell number as a key and stores the output as the value.

```py
type(Out)
>>>> dict
```

You can access both the code that was executed and the results from within other cells of the notebook.

Comment: In my notebooks I don't see "In" nor "Out" when a cell is executed. Only the number shows up to the left  of the cell once it's executed.

Comment: That may be a custom style. Execute a cell that returns some result in the output cell and in the next cell execute the following code: `print(In[CELL_NUMBER])` where `CELL_NUMBER` is the number of the previously executed cell. The expected output of the new cell is the executed code string. `print(Out[CELL_NUMBER])` should output the result seen in the corresponding output cell.